# sentiment140 dataset doesn't contain label 2 i.e neutral sentences when uploading it from HuggingFace

Tags: dataset, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-datasets, huggingface

I want to work with the sentiment140 dataset for a sentiment analysis task, as I saw that it contains normally the following labels :

- 0, 4 for pos and neg sentences
- 2 for neutral sentences
  which I found when looking at the dataset on their website :
  https://huggingface.co/datasets/sentiment140#data-fields

But after importing it on my notebook it tells me that it contains just two labels :

- 0 for neg
- 4 for pos !!!

[image]

So how to get full dataset with the three labels ?

Comment: How did you load the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on the fact that the HuggingFace sentiment140 dataset only contains 2 labels in the training set (0 and 4); however, the test set contains the 3 labels (0, 2 and 4).

You could open a discussion [here](https://huggingface.co/datasets/sentiment140/discussions) to ask the authors if this is normal.